# Intermittent connection to SQL server database. “The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication”

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having some random intermittemt issues connecting to a database which is running on a SQL Server 2008 instance, connected into an Active Directory 2003 domain. It's only suddenly started doing it, all the workstations are Windows 7 Professional 32Bit, and the AD domain is a server 2003 domain controller.

There is no apparent definite fault, its totally intermittent, and if the workstation is rebooted a few times it will then connect Ok with no issues. This is not just one workstation it happens randomly to other workstations sometimes. There is no apparent fault in the network setup they are running on Gb network connections via cisco Gb switch, all other windows features and network drives have no issues.

The SQL Server is running on very new 64bit hardware from Dell so its not a hardware issue. It has been running like this OK for some time and this random connection issue has only just recently started to happen. Could it be the size of the database? the mdf file as grown to 32Gb, and the log file is a whopping 135Gb in size. The database was migrated from a SQL Server 2000 database server about 12 months ago.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have had the same issue.  Works perfectly 99% of the time, but intermittently fails.  It is running in the domain and shares the same server / connection as a number of other batch apps.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/05/02/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection/

The basic take-away for this ticket is:

If this error message only appears sporadically in an application using Windows Authentication, it may result because the SQL Server cannot contact the Domain Controller to validate the user.  This may be caused by high network load stressing the hardware, or to a faulty piece of networking equipment.  The next step here is to troubleshoot the network hardware between the SQL Server and the Domain Controller by taking network traces and replacing network hardware as necessary.

The fact that your log file has grown so dramatically, could be some cause for concern.  You may want to back up more often, i.e. log and DIFF to reduce your high log requirement (and likely increase speed).  Confirm that your daily maintenance tasks are running (index and stats).

In my case, the high write rate (150k writes per hour and about 500k reads per hour) had some bearing on my issues - and reducing the hammering of the database reduced my issues with SQL not "getting to" the AD server timeously.

You could also use a SQL user (to avoid the AD lookup), but getting to the bottom of the issue is probably more in your interest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to understand what may call the issue so I guess you need to do some further investigations (It could be your DNS,AD,ETC,).

SQL Server 2008 has a features to investigate connection issues called Connectivity Ring Buffer

More info can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/20/connectivity-troubleshooting-in-sql-server-2008-with-the-connectivity-ring-buffer.aspx)